# Single handler for 200 buttons does not behave as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I am creating a button engine design, where one handler can be used by up to 200 buttons.

If I directly touch any of the buttons, the handler fires. Currently, I just set that button's alpha to zero to hide it.

I was also able to set it up so that if I slide/drag through a button, the handler fires, and the correct buttons alpha is set to zero.

However, if I touch down in a button, then slide to another button, then only the first button touch is handled and only one button disappears.  If I don't touch down inside any buttons, then I can drag through dozens of buttons and they will all disappear.

Is there something I can set upon touchdown inside a button that will then allow me to drag to other buttons and have the handler fire?

It looks like touchesMoved is not getting called until I release the button I touch down in by picking up my finger.  Once I touch the screen while not inside any button's frame then touchesMoved will get called. Is there any way to force a simulated release of a button after touchdown, and before a touchup, so that touchesMoved will start getting called again without having to pick up your finger?

Below is associated code :

```
- (void) GenericButtonHandler: (UIButton *) sender {

// triggers 1 of 200 buttons if dragged through, all using this handler based on the sender.
     UIButton *btnSender;
     btnSender = (UIButton *)sender;
     btnSender.alpha = 0;
}  

GenericButton001 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[GenericButton001 addTarget: self action:@selector(GenericButtonHandler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.view addSubview:GenericButton001];
[GenericButton001 setAlpha:1.0];
GenericButton001.tag = 1;

GenericButton002 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[GenericButton002 addTarget: self action:@selector(GenericButtonHandler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.view addSubview:GenericButton002];
[GenericButton002 setAlpha:1.0];
GenericButton002.tag = 2;
```

....

I call touchPointIsInsideAnyButton in touchesMoved passing it the current touch point :

```
touchPointIsInsideAnyButton(pointToProcess);
```

and here is how it is coded :

```
static void touchPointIsInsideAnyButton (CGPoint point){

    resetGenericButtonIndexing();

    UIButton * localButton;     

    for (int i = 1; i < 201; i++) {

        localButton = getNextGenericButton();

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(localButton.frame, point) && localButton.alpha == 1)
            [localButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    }
} // ends touchPointIsInsideAnyButton
```

resetGenericButtonIndexing is a function that I use to keep the button indexing in sync.

```
static void  resetGenericButtonIndexing () {

    genericButtonIndex = 1;
}
```

Here's how I get the next generic button :

```
static UIButton *  getNextGenericButton () {

    UIButton * tempButton = GenericButton001;

    switch (genericButtonIndex) {
        case 1:
            tempButton = GenericButton001;
            break;
        case 2:
            tempButton = GenericButton002;
            break;
        case 3:
            tempButton = GenericButton003;
            break;
        case 4:
            tempButton = GenericButton004;
            break;
        case 5:
            tempButton = GenericButton005;
            break;
        case 6:
            tempButton = GenericButton006;
            break;
    ....

    return tempButton;
} // ends getNextGenericButton
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you are nothing using the right tools to do this. How about using an invisible view above your buttons to track where the user tapped, if he is dragging, dropping etc, and fire your events based on the results?

Take a look at UIView's touch events API

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

to figure out a better way to do this.

Comment: I've edited the description and added more detail.  I do implement touchesBegan and touchesMoved.  I kind of liked how CGRectContainsPoint(localButton.frame, point) will check to see if the touch point is in the frame of the specified button.  That seems to make my task easier in ways.

Comment: It looks like touchesMoved is not getting called again until I release the button.  Is there any way to force a simulated release of the button so that touchesMoved will start getting called again?

Comment: How about NOT tapping the button directly? I mean, if you have an invisible view above that blocks but tracks the user gestures, you can just fire the buttons from there without passing the gesture to the button. And I'm curious. Are you making a reference of all your 200 buttons one by one? If yes, I can show you how to improve this too.